# Change hover color on a button with Bootstrap customization

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to style my buttons in a way that the hover makes the button a lighter shade instead of a darker shade. I tried bootstrap customization page(http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and it doesn't give me an option to change the button hover color. I tried doing this manually by inspecting the CSS but it is unclear how the buttons are getting the hover color. I tried another bootstrap customization website

http://pikock.github.io/bootstrap-magic/app/#!/editor

I wanted the main color to be #0495c9 and the hover color to be #00b3db but I am only able to specify the button bg color and not it's hover color.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you post your code or a link to jsFiddle? Aren't you able to simply use `button { background-color: #0495c9 }` and `button:hover { background-color: #00b3db }`?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The color for your buttons comes from the btn-x classes (e.g., btn-primary, btn-success), so if you want to manually change the colors by writing your own custom css rules, you'll need to change:

```
/*This is modifying the btn-primary colors but you could create your own .btn-something class as well*/
.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0495c9;
    border-color: #357ebd; /*set the color you want here*/
}
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00b3db;
    border-color: #285e8e; /*set the color you want here*/
}
```

Comment: In addition you may also want to set `.btn-primary:active:focus` to prevent it flickering.

Comment: In case it is not working, add **!important** after each colour

Answer (score 15):

or can do this...
set all btn ( class name like : `.btn-` + `$theme-colors: map-merge` ) styles at one time :

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .btn-#{$color} {
    @include button-variant($value, $value,
    // modify
    $hover-background: lighten($value, 7.5%),
    $hover-border: lighten($value, 10%),
    $active-background: lighten($value, 10%),
    $active-border: lighten($value, 12.5%)
    // /modify
    );
  }
}

// code from "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_buttons.scss"
```

should add into your customization scss file.

Comment: You should add better explanation and proper example for those that do not know much SASS.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add `!important` to get it to work. I also made my own class `button-primary-override`.

```
.button-primary-override:hover, 
.button-primary-override:active,
.button-primary-override:focus,
.button-primary-override:visited{
    background-color: #42A5F5 !important;
    border-color: #42A5F5 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to change btn color.

```
 .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, 
    .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, 
    .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle{
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #F7B432;
        border-color: #F7B432;
    }
```

Comment: why is that no `:hover` in your examle?

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 5 you can change the button background on hover like this:

```
.status-btn:hover, .status-btn:focus, .status-btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .status-btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .status-btn.dropdown-toggle {
    color: black;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-color: blue;
}
```