# How to change text color in button hover property

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, hover

I used this guide to customize buttons in a web page I've made with bootstrap:

[Change hover color on a button with Bootstrap customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923623/change-hover-color-on-a-button-with-bootstrap-customization)

The problem is that I can't manage to keep the same font-color in hover and I can't explain why it always changes to dark grey.
Here's the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByKZZK

HTML:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<button href="mailto:abc@def.ghi" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block">info@mail.org&nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-custom {
    color: #FFD180;;
    background-color: #483737;
    border-color: #357ebd; /*set the color you want here*/
}
.btn-custom:hover, .btn-custom:focus, .btn-custom:active, .btn-custom.active, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-custom {
    color: #FFD180;
    background-color: #837171;
    border-color: #837171; /*set the color you want here*/
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I just want to point out the double semi-colon here `color: #FFD180;;`

Comment: @Mattigins, that's `;;` the spider face operator. It means there was a declaration there, but it got eaten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like some way the `.btn` class of bootstrap is getting more weight on your codepen, you can try to avoid the `!important` making more specific your selector like:

> .btn.btn-custom

Check the **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByKZOQ)**

Comment: Excellent answer

Answer (score 5):

Just add `!important;` to the `color: #FFD180` in the `hover` part of your CSS.

```
.btn-custom:hover, .btn-custom:focus, .btn-custom:active, .btn-custom.active, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-custom {
    color: #FFD180 !important;
    background-color: #837171;
    border-color: #837171; /*set the color you want here*/
}
```

Edit: The color (#333) probably comes from this line in the `bootstrap.min.css`

```
.dropdown-toggle.btn-default{color:#333;background-color:#e6e6e6;border-color:#adadad}
```